# Laravel 5.3 - Clear config cache in shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, caching

Currently I'm working on small project that require me to host my laravel app on shared hosting (please ignore the reason why I didn't use VPS to host my laravel project) and this hosting provider disable escapeshellarg() for security reason so I can't use `php artisan config:cache` to clear config cache.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`config:clear` command just deletes `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file, so just delete this file manually.

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43446010/1085499) solved my problem after going through all other solutions.

Comment: You can also manually modify cached config file. Just a note.

Comment: Lifesaver! Finally error 500 on shared hosting was solved!

Answer (score 19):

You can call artisan commands programmatically

```
Artisan::call('config:clear');
```

This can be helpful in setups where the PHP user has a different set of permissions than the FTP user (so files created by PHP cannot be deleted via FTP)

Answer (score 8):

try this command for clear all cached data at once.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

###### because Laravel 5 is deprecated now, the answers are not good enough.

**So I explain for Laravel > 7**

I read all the answers but none of them contain `optimize:clear` so I want to write my answer for future users.

`optimize:clear` is **the most powerful** command to clean **all** the **caches**

in Laravel >= 7 you have this command for clearing all the caches

**Command:**

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

It will clear: `Compiled views`, `Application cache`, `Route cache`, `Configuration cache`, `Compiled services and packages`.

It is not harmful at all. and it won't affect any single line of your codes. it just will clear all your cached files.

after running this command you will see:

```
Compiled views cleared!
Application cache cleared!
Route cache cleared!
Configuration cache cleared!
Compiled services and packages files removed!
Caches cleared successfully!
```

Comment: This kills the session for anyone who is logged in. So it is not harmless.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is nice tiny library for shared hosting and typing clear bunch of clear commands one by one..

simply just install it once, and clear all caching issues in laravel with just one command.

[Laracake](https://github.com/laracake/laravel-clear)

This is very handy

```
composer require laracake/clearall --dev
```

After installation

```
php artisan laracake:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I restart queue server on live

```
## Restart redis and terminate curent jobs
php artisan config:clear ## clear config
sudo -i
cd /var/www/html
php artisan horizon:terminate ## need to be sudo , else throw permission error
php artisan queue:restart
exit
```