# Mail is not sending forget password link using SendsPasswordResetEmails class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, reset-password

here is my code..
reset password view is open but when i put mail id and click on sent it redirect login page but mail not received. please help... thanks in advance

reset.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="clearfix" style="height: 70px;"></div>
                <div class="login-form">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h6>@lang('forms.reset_password')</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="control-label">@lang('forms.email')</label>
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="control-label">@lang('forms.password')</label>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="control-label">@lang('forms.confirm_password')</label>
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                @lang('buttons.reset_password')
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

route file(web.php)

```
 Route::post('/password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
```

.env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl
```

ForgotPasswordController.php(controller)

```
<?php
/**
 * Indusrabbit - SMM Panel script
 * Domain: https://indusrabbit.com/
 * Codecanyon Item: https://codecanyon.net/item/indusrabbit-smm-panel/19821624
 *
 */
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

?>
SendsPasswordResetEmails.php file (locate in vendor laravel/framework)

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
{
    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
            //$data['email']
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the email for the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset link.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkResponse($response)
    {
        return back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(
            ['email' => trans($response)]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Laravel Dev, but In your `.env` file, your `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` should be `tls` or maybe `ssl`.

`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Answer (score 0):

Spelling is wrong in the email encryption. It should be `tls` instead of `tsl`. I've used `ssl` which is working perfectly.
So,
Your environment configuration should look like this,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=youremail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

And make sure to clear configuration cache with following command,

```
php artisan config:cache
```

I hope you will understand.

Comment: @PradeepParker linux server or some other ?

Comment: yes.. its linux server..
does need to set any path for this command?

Comment: @PradeepParker you have to run this command from root directory of the project or you can manually delete `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file. for safety purpose, you can rename the file like config_old.php in case of any problem you can just raname that file again to config.php, See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521837/laravel-5-3-clear-config-cache-in-shared-hosting

Comment: but there is no config file under bootstrap/cache directory? @sagargautam

Comment: @PradeepParker then, it's a strange problem