# How to refresh .ENV file in Laravel's Forge?

Tags: php, laravel

I've made a change to my .ENV file and the new changes are not taking effect inside Laravel's Forge.  How do I tell Forge to re-fetch/re-fresh it?

I've restarted all services.  No difference.  Still using old data from previous ENV.  I've setup Forge to use BitBucket repo and AWS.

Comment: Clear the configuration cache

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel not reading changes to .env file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-not-reading-changes-to-env-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.env` file isn't cached, however the config is. You can try running `php artisan config:clear` which removes the configuration cache file.

You can look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521837/laravel-5-3-clear-config-cache-in-shared-hosting) for more info.